# How can I change the option value of a select boxed based on a selection of another select box

Tags: jquery, html

In my code below I am trying to change the options of the second select box based on what I select at the first one. So when I select the `value="1"` from the first select box, the second select box must change to `value="3"` etc.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#itemconditionid').change(function() {
    $('#meta_itemcondition').val($(this).val())
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="itemconditionid">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">New</option>
  <option value="2">Used</option>
</select>

<select id="meta_itemcondition">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="3">Yeah! It's New Baby</option>
  <option value="4">Ouch! I hate used stuff</option>
</select>
```

Comment: so you want 3 to be selected when 1 is selected?

Comment: Nope. When i select "New" at the first select box then the selection of the second box must be "Yeah! It's New Bay".

When i select "Used" at the first select box then the selection of the second box must be "Ouch! I hate used stuff".

Comment: Just set your values properly in meta... !

Comment: Isn't that the same thing? 1 is the New in first select , 3 is the Yeah... in second select

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I misunderstood your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selectedIndex` . Change second drop down option based on that index.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#itemconditionid').change(function() {
    $("#meta_itemcondition").prop('selectedIndex', $(this)[0].selectedIndex);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="itemconditionid">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">New</option>
  <option value="2">Used</option>
</select>

<select id="meta_itemcondition">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="3">Yeah! It's New Baby</option>
  <option value="4">Ouch! I hate used stuff</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another attribute to each of the options in the first select (In this case `data-value`), and use the value of the attribute to define the value of the second select:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#itemconditionid').change(function(){  
 $('#meta_itemcondition').val( $(this).children('option:selected').data('value') )
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="itemconditionid">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="1" data-value="3">New</option>
    <option value="2" data-value="4">Used</option>
    </select>

<select id="meta_itemcondition">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="3">Yeah! It's New Baby</option>
    <option value="4">Ouch! I hate used stuff</option>
    </select>
```